# View All Table / Database Constraints in MySQL

Tags: mysql, constraints

How do you view all the constraints (Primary keys, Secondary keys, Assertions , Triggers, etc) in a MySQL Database / Table in the command line environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just dump the database without data using

```
mysqldump --no-data  (other options)
```

As if you were taking a backup. Use the same options as you do when taking a backup (maybe --lock-tables=0 - you don't need a lock when dumping the schema)

Without the data, you get just the schema which includes all those things you said above.

Comment: I tried this but am unable to use this option as I don't have the permission to lock tables/dbs

Comment: You do not need to lock the tables to dump the schema. I specifically suggested not trying to.

Comment: sry! I missed that.

This is a better solution I guess. Dumps all the information it has.
Syntax:
mysqldump -uusername -hhostname -p --no-data --lock-tables=0 dbname

More details available at
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

DESCRIBE is an alias for SHOW COLUMNS, like a shortcut. If you want all the other stuff then you need to use SHOW  commands for your stuff. And SHOW COLUMNS for the rest.

[Describe](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/describe.html)

[Show](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html)

Comment: Thanks Arto!

I googled on this and there exists a series of commands for this purpose. Please refer
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show.html